Openssl cannot verify CA cert and then it can verify it all in the same operation?
Open ssl debug reports first that it cannot verify the CA cert, and then that it can verify it during the course of just one command, why?
openssl s_client -connect 3d.example.com:443 -debug
depth=0 CN = *.example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate

But it also at the same time, further down in the same output it also says:
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=*.example.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
1 s:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=AAA Certificate Services

So why is it both unable to verify and also able to verify at the same time?
This is causing the following error when some clients try to connect (some other clients are unaffected):
SSL_do_handshake() failed 
(SSL: error:0A000412:SSL routines::sslv3 alert bad certificate:
SSL alert number 42) while SSL handshaking

I'm thinking that probably the affected clients are using TLS 1.3 and the other clients are using 1.2.
The site has a wildcard cert *.example.com that I've used successfully on many other sites, eg api.example.com, portal.example.com, staging.example.com and so on.  These sites have the correct output from openssl s_client -debug.
I have verified that I did correctly copy the exact same wildcard cert, the CA cert and the private key to this new site: 3d.example.com.
My nginx config for all above sites has the same ssl section, and this works for all but one site:
server {
  # the ssl cert and the ca cert are bundled to one file
  ssl_certificate   /etc/ssl/example.com.bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;
}

The ssl cert and the CA cert are already bundled together, ssl first then CA 2nd. The showcerts command shows both certs:
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 3d.example.com:443
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=0 CN = *.example.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.example.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
write W BLOCK
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=*.example.com
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
M...[correctly shows my cert]...k=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:/C=US/ST=New Jersey/L=Jersey City/O=The USERTRUST Network/CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=AAA Certificate Services
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
M...[correctly shows the CA cert]...V
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/CN=*.example.com
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Sectigo Limited/CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3581 bytes and written 367 bytes

The showcerts command shows my cert is cert 0, and the CA cert is cert 1.

"So why is it both unable to verify and also able to verify at the same time?" - your first output from s_client  is about failing to validate the certificate chain, the second is about showing the certs send by the peer. Obviously these cert+chain is not sufficient to validate against a root CA known locally to the client. Root CA send by the server are ignored - only chain certificates are used to build the trust chain to a local root CA.

Sorry I don't quite follow.  Are you saying the client does not know the CA?  Client in this case is my macbook since openssl showcerts runs locally.  I have checked and the 2 certs are bundled and nginx is set up to send the bundle, not the ssl by itself.  I have just copied how this was setup from some other sites using the same wildcard cert that have been running for years.

openssl does not come with its own trust store and will not use the system trust store by default on MacOS and Windows because they use storage backends incompatible with most versions of openssl. On Linux and *BSD it is instead usually well integrated to use the system trust store. This means it is pretty common that openssl verification fails on Windows and Mac.  As for why it fails for some selected clients of you - no idea. But it very likely has nothing to do with TLS 1.2 vs. TLS 1.3. Depending on your server config it might be IPv4 vs. IPv6 or RSA vs. ECDSA cert.

I recommend that you check your site with https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html and look for any problems it might find. If there are none the problem might be at the clients end.

Thanks thats good to know about the Mac.  openssl showcerts on the linux VM has the same output "unable to get local issuer certificate".  My cert is issued by Sectigo, and the CA cert is showing USERTRUST and Comodo in the openssl output.  Does this mean it is the wrong CA cert?

ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html is saying "certificate chain incomplete" which is probably the cause of the problem.  It also says "DNS CAA - No" which is probably not the problem but I will update it anyway

Confirmed: it was a missing CA cert.  I was only sending USERTRUST.  I added Sectigo as well, and it is working.  Thanks, all comments helped very much to lead to this solution.  Its strange that connecting to the site with Chrome, Edge etc shows no errors and viewing the cert says everything is ok.

"Its strange that connecting to the site with Chrome, Edge etc shows no errors and viewing the cert says everything is ok." - There are many trust path and what is used depends on what the client has in the trust store. See https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-Chain-Hierarchy-and-Intermediate-Roots


But it also at the same time, further down in the same output it also says

This does NOT say that the certificate is valid - its just assertions about the content of the certificate.
You need to add the intermediate certificate to the file presented by nginx. This is appended AFTER your service certificate, e.g.
cp /etc/ssl/example.com.crt /etc/ssl/combined.crt
cat /etc/ssl/intermediate.crt >>/etc/ssl/combined.crt

(and point ssl_certificate to combined.crt in nginx config).

Thanks yes I thought about that possibility and doubled checked before asking.  My cert and the CA cert are bundled.  I have updated the question above with the output from "openssl showcerts"

One of the steps in my Docker file has always been cat ssl.crt CA.crt >> /etc/ssl/example.com/bundle.crt, and nginx is setup with ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com/bundle.crt.  I have checked inside the image and confirmed that the bundle file is there and correctly  has both certs, mine first, then the CA.

Helpful - but read what you posted. Your certificate is signed by "CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA" but the certificate you appended is "CN=USERTrust RSA Certification Authority"

I suspect you added the CA cert, not the intermediate cert (adding the CA cert is just a waste of bandwidth).
